# Codeigniter Session Class userdata?

Tags: codeigniter-2

i have some question in Codeigniter session class:

1. whats different between these

   ```
   $this->session->all_userdata(); 
   $this->session->userdata
   ```

   both of them return array of all user data in ci session (cooke).
2. and why this code is wrong:

   ```
   $this->session->userdata();
   ```

   but this one is correct:

   ```
   $this->session->userdata
   ```

   why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for 1:
`$this->session->all_userdata();` is method to get CI-session's data
`$this->session->userdata` is variable of CI-session's class, You shouldn't get session's data this way.

for 2:
`$this->session->userdata();` is correct because this way You'll use `setters-getters` mechanism (read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters)), `$this->session->userdata` is incorrect because You try to get data directly (read link above to get more info)